# Can jQuery template bind to a raw array

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Given

```
<div id="place_holder" />

<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
WHAT DO I PUT HERE
</script>

var array_of_ints = [1,2,3]

$( "#template" )
        .tmpl( array_of_ints   )
        .appendTo( "#place_holder" );
```

What can I put within the template to get ?

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ul id="place_holder">
</ul>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>${}</li>       
</script>

var array_of_ints = [1,2,3]

$("#template")
    .tmpl(array_of_ints)
    .appendTo( "#place_holder" );
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<div id="place_holder" />

<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{= $data}}
</script>

var array_of_ints = [1,2,3]

$( "#template" )
    .tmpl( array_of_ints   )
    .appendTo( "#place_holder" );
```

{{= $data}} works everywhere ( ${} wont work in strings in the template )

Comment: What do you mean by ${} wont work in strings in the template? Can you give an example where {{= $data}} works but ${} doesn't?

Comment: setting tag attributes like name and src

Answer (score 1):

${} didn't work for me with an array of strings ['A String','Another String','Yet Another String'] , but {{= $data}} does.  thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You want to look into the [`{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) template tag.

In this case, I don't think that jQuery.tmpl is really the best way to do this. It would be much easier in my opinion just to use a standard `for` loop.

```
var array_of_ints = [1,2,3];

//creates the ul
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');

//creates the LI's
for(var i = 0; i < array_of_ints.length; i++){
    ul.append('<li>' + array_of_ints[i] + '</li>');
}

//adds to the placeholder
$('#placeholder').append(ul);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LeKYu/

Comment: The question was asking whether it can be done using jQuery.tmpl

Comment: @Michael Wolfenden: I understand that, which is why I posted the link to the `{{each}}` template tag. I would recommend changing your example, because using jQuery.tmpl for this is completely pointless. A more realistic example would better serve you and any future readers.

Comment: @Michael Wolfdenden: I'm also fairly sure there is no way for you to get access to the root object. What it's doing is for each object/value in the array, it's calling the template, rather than calling the template with the array.